# Excel/VBA File Creation Date

Tags: excel, vba

When creating a new file using VBA like so...

```
FileCopy "\\JACKSONVILLE-DC\Common\SOP's for JV\SOP Audits\SOP Audit Checklist-Template.xlsx", _
         "\\JACKSONVILLE-DC\Common\SOP's for JV\SOP Audits\2019\" & NewAuditFileName
```

Where is the system pulling the date/time to tell Windows when the file was created? Currently, for a file created yesterday (7/31/19) it shows the Date Created in Windows as 3/19/2019 with a Date Modified as 7/31/2019.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this it is essentially the same as copying and pasting in Windows Explorer.

Therefore the Created and Modified dates will be those of the source file.